# Remove duplicate words from two variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

I want to remove all the occurences of words that appears in `VAR1` that also appears in `VAR2`.

For example for:

```
VAR1=a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a1
VAR2=a1,a2,a6,a4,a7,a8
```

I want the result will be:

```
VAR1=a3,a5
VAR2=a7,a8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extended **`tr`** + **`sort`** + **`paste`** + **`comm`** solution:

```
VAR1="a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a1"
VAR2="a1,a2,a6,a4,a7,a8"
temp1="$VAR1"
temp2="$VAR2"

VAR1=$(comm -23 <(tr ',' '\n' <<<"$temp1" | sort) <(tr ',' '\n' <<<"$temp2" | sort) | paste -d',' -s)
VAR2=$(comm -13 <(tr ',' '\n' <<<"$temp1" | sort) <(tr ',' '\n' <<<"$temp2" | sort) | paste -d',' -s)
```

Results:

```
$ echo "$VAR1"
a3,a5

$ echo "$VAR2"
a7,a8
```

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`, you'd use its array subtraction operators:

```
$ VAR1=a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a1
$ VAR2=a1,a2,a6,a4,a7,a8
$ array1=(${(s:,:)VAR1})
$ array2=(${(s:,:)VAR2})
$ echo ${(j:,:)array1:|array2}
a3,a5
$ echo ${(j:,:)array2:|array1}
a7,a8
```

Answer (score 0):

In below script i have assigned tmp1=$VAR1 and tmp2=$VAR2  as temperory variable.

Below `awk` one liner script is tested and it worked fine

```
tmp1=$VAR1;tmp2=$VAR2

 VAR1=$(awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next}!($1 in a) {print $1}' <(echo $tmp2|perl -pne "s/,/\n/g") <(echo $tmp1|perl -pne "s/,/\n/g")|perl -pne "s/\n/,/g"| sed "s/,$//g")



VAR2=$(awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next}!($1 in a) {print $1}' <(echo $tmp1|perl -pne "s/,/\n/g") <(echo $tmp2|perl -pne "s/,/\n/g")|perl -pne "s/\n/,/g"| sed "s/,$//g")
```

output

```
echo $VAR1
```

a3,a5

```
echo $VAR2
```

a7,a8

Comment: Kindly clarify why downvoted for my answer as it provides the same result

Comment: I did not downvote you. Your code is making several unnecessary calls. For example `perl -pne "s/\n/,/g"|sed "s/,$//g"` can be replaced `paste -sd,`  Also, for perl, use one of `-p` or `-n` but not both. The `g` flag in sed is not required since the regex is anchored so it can match at most once per line. You don't quote any variables.

Comment: I up voted your answer, not because I think it’s good or really worthy of an up vote,  but because it inspired my answer, and I always up vote answers that I use.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash associative arrays to hold the results, loop through each, remove the ones in common, then rejoining the arrays into the original variables:

```bsh
VAR1=a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a1
VAR2=a1,a2,a6,a4,a7,a8

OIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
declare -A v1 v2
set -f
for v in $VAR1
do
  v1["$v"]=1
done

for v in $VAR2
do
  v2["$v"]=1
done

for v in "${!v1[@]}"
do
  #if it's there, remove it from v1 too
  if [[ ${v2[$v]} -eq 1 ]]
  then
    unset v1["$v"]
    unset v2["$v"]
  fi
done
for v in "${!v2[@]}"
do
  #if it's there, remove it from v2 too
  if [[ ${v1[$v]} -eq 1 ]]
  then
    unset v1["$v"]
    unset v2["$v"]
  fi
done


VAR1=$(set -- "${!v1[@]}"; IFS=,; echo "$*")
VAR2=$(set -- "${!v2[@]}"; IFS=,; echo "$*")
unset v1 v2
IFS=$OIFS
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach to Jeff's answer, but using perl

```
source <(
    perl -se '
        @v1 = split /,/, $v1;
        @v2 = split /,/, $v2;
        @h1{@v1} = (1) x @v1; delete @h1{@v2};
        @h2{@v2} = (1) x @v2; delete @h2{@v1};
        printf qq{VAR1only="%s"\n}, join ",", keys %h1;
        printf qq{VAR2only="%s"\n}, join ",", keys %h2;
    ' -- -v1="$VAR1" -v2="$VAR2"
)

echo "$VAR1only -- $VAR2only"
```

```
a3,a5 -- a7,a8
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on [the answer by Praveen Kumar BS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/417958/80216#418027):

```
tmp1="$VAR1"
tmp2="$VAR2"
awk_prog='BEGIN {FS=","; ORS=","}
        NR==1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[$i]}
        NR==2 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (!($i in a)) print $i}'
VAR1=$(printf '%s\n' "$tmp2" "$tmp1" | awk "$awk_prog" | sed 's/,$//')
VAR2=$(printf '%s\n' "$tmp1" "$tmp2" | awk "$awk_prog" | sed 's/,$//')
```

- Since we’re doing the exact same thing twice,
  save the `awk` program in a variable rather than typing it twice.
- Set the **f**ield **s**eparator (*input* field separator) to comma (`,`),
  so awk will break the comma-separated input strings apart appropriately,
  and we don’t need to use another program to change commas to newlines.
- Set the **o**utput **r**ecord **s**eparator (ORS) to comma,
  so when we say `print something`,
  the output is `something,`
  rather than `something(newline)`,
  and we don’t need to use another program to change newlines to commas.
- The first line (`NR==1`) of input to `awk` is the string
  that contains the words that we want to remove (from the other string). 
  Using a trick that should be somewhat well known by now,
  and is described in more detail elsewhere on this site,
  “remember” the words from this string
  by creating an element in the associative array `a`
  with the word as an index.
- The second line (`NR==2`) of input to `awk` is the string
  that contains the words that we want to keep
  (unless they also appear in the other string). 
  For each word on this line, print it,
  unless it’s flagged in the `a` array
  as having been seen in the first string.
- This notion of the first string and the second string
  appearing as the first line and the second line, respectively,
  will break if either of the strings contains newline(s). 
  If this is a possibility, change the initialization to

  ```
  tmp1="$(tr '\n' ',' <<< "$VAR1")"
  tmp2="$(tr '\n' ',' <<< "$VAR2")"
  ```

  Note that the “here string” (`<<<`) syntax is not POSIX-compliant
  and might not work in shells other than bash.
- `VAR1` should be set to the words that aren’t in `tmp2` but are in `tmp1`,
  and vice versa.
- Every “line” (record) of output from `awk`
  ends with a comma instead of a newline,
  so use `sed` to remove a comma (if any) from the end. 
  (We could have done this entirely in `awk`, but this way is easier.)